# Anaconda - Updating a package via anaconda prompt is constricted

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I want to update all my packages that I am currently using. Going into anaconda prompt and typing

`conda update --all`

returns me the message that **"All requested packages already installed"**. That isn't the case, since almost half of my packages are outdated. I understand that anaconda is doing that just because of dependency conflicts. So I tried to manually update 1 package, in my case, pandas.

Typing `conda update pandas`, give me the message

```
Updating pandas is constricted by 
anaconda -> requires pandas==0.25.1=py37ha925a31_0

If you are sure you want an update of your package either try `conda update --all` or install a 
specific version of the package you want using `conda install <pkg>=<version>`
```

So does that mean that I can't update pandas to the latest version? Or for that matter, any other library like numpy which yields me the same message. Is this normal or am I missing something ?

Comment: Can you get the `anaconda` package to update? E.g., `conda update anaconda`, or perhaps more explicitly: `conda install anaconda=2020.7`

Comment: Thanks for the asnwer. I typed in anaconda prompt "conda install anaconda=2020.07" but it is stuck in the "solving environment" step. No clue what this mean sadly. Do you have any idea? EDIT: It worked, its updating packages on its own as it installing anaconda 2020.07. It is also downgrading 4-5 packages, including tensorflow. Is this ok?

Comment: downgrading is not uncommon, especially if you may have upgraded something previously. Whether it is "ok" all depends on your individual software needs. Also, you may be able to manually upgrade it back later. In general, I find it is better practice to create new environments for modular purposes rather than try to get a monolithic environment to have all the latest versions of everything one ever uses.

Comment: Thank you. All these sould so allien to me, im not familiar at all with these things..I ended up messing everything up and anaconda just got deleted somehow..no idea what happened. I reinstalled it and Im trying to install keras/tensorflow and they dont even appear on the not installed section. This is a rollercoaster of problems lol..

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue as you was able to resolve it  by updating to latest anaconda, you need to type in

```
conda install anaconda=2020.07
```

And that should update everythign to the latest package, got my pandas to 1.0.5 as well as updated a lot of other packages